# RESTful API testing in a browser

Tags: javascript, rest, jasmine, supertest

I'm writing RESTful application, along with a documentation. Because the documentation is written as a web page, I'd like to have REST services testing embedded in the docs.

I use Jasmine for testing and have been looking for some simplification of testing REST calls. [Frisby](http://frisbyjs.com/) looks like the thing I need, but [it is run inside Node.js, not a browser](https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/issues/95).

Do you know of any library that would resemble Frisby testing, but in browser environment? For what it's worth, I found [SuperTest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest), which runs on portable [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/), but I don't know if it's usable with Jasmine (they are strongly Mocha-related).

**UPDATE**: Nope, [supertest doesn't (yet) work in the browser](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/122) :(

Comment: Mayber superagent is something for you? (https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)

Comment: There is also supertest that builds on top (https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest), but im not entirely sure if you can integrate it within the browser...

Comment: @Charminbear I have already mentioned them in a question...

Comment: durr, sorry, i totally overread that. Well since superagent is mainly an AJAX-Lib and not related to tests, I would say you could also use it with jasmine. But well, its probably not the Call itself but the assertions you are worried about?

Comment: Right, compact and elegant assertions is what I'm looking for

Comment: This is not the way you should test REST APIs. In your client you should use the hypermedia response to get the links you want to follow (aka HATEOAS principle). Currently your tests are the client, so you should parse the response and follow the links, instead of building HTTP requests, URIs, etc. manually. So forget what you learned by SOAP, it won't work... What you need is a REST browser, which can parse the responses and follow the links it founds in them. What you need is just another simple REST client and a testing framework which supports async tests, for example jasmine...

Comment: By HTML responses you can use http://nightwatchjs.org/, by non-HTML responses you have to write something similar to process and test your choice of MIME type.

Comment: @inf3rno I don't know what your assumptions come from (esp. about SOAP); I said nothing about the structure of the API. But if you insist on your vocabulary, yes, I'm looking for a REST browser *with nice assertions* about received representations, as well as HTTP responses on the whole (e.g. checking status codes, headers, etc.). Following links is really not enough...

Answer (score 0):

I ended with writing my own small set of helper functions wrapping SuperAgent. Now testing code (CoffeeScript and Jasmine) looks like:

```
describe "A suite", ->
    resource = null

    it "and a spec", (done) ->
        expectResponse(request.get "/path/to/resource")
            .ok()
            .json()
            .andDo (response) -> resource = response.body
            .end(done)
```

and a helper class looks like this

```
class ExpectResponseWrapper
    constructor: (req) ->
        @req = req
        @expectations = []

    end: (done) ->
        @req.end (err, res) =>
            if (err)
                expect( -> throw err).not.toThrow()
            else
                for exp in @expectations
                    exp(res)
            done?()

    ok: ->
        @expectations.push (res) ->
            expect(res.statusType).toEqual(2)
        this

    json: ->
        @expectations.push (res) ->
            expect(res.type).toEqual('application/json')
        this

    andDo: (fn) ->
        @expectations.push fn
        this

    # ... and the list of other helper expectations goes on ...

expectResponse = (req) -> new ExpectResponseWrapper(req)
```